# How to Unit Test method that calls NSDate()?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift, nsdate

I'm currently using Swift.

My question is simple, how do you unit test a method that create an object in a database with NSDate() as a property?

The problem is that on my assert I'll create a new NSDate() like this:

```
let expectedObject = Object(data: NSDate())
XCTAssertEqual(database.objects(), [expectedObject])
```

And the assert will fail because the 2 NSDates are slightly different.

Thank you.

Comment: how about stubbing all calls to nsdate?

Comment: with kiwi it would be a call like  [ [dateObject should] receive:@selector(currentGear) andReturn:theValue(3)]; there are different mocking frameworks, or you could use method swizzling

Comment: none of those options are supported with Swift.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in https://testdriven-ios.com

a very good approach is to override the NSDate.date in the test case forcing it to return a known date

```
@implementation NSDate (custom)

+ (instancetype)date{
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = NSDateFormatter.new;
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
    return [formatter dateFromString:@"2017-12-28 13:00:10+0000"];
}

@end
```

Then everywhere where NSDate.date is called, the `2017-12-28 13:00:10+0000` will be returned

```
@implementation NSDate (custom)

+ (instancetype)date{
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = NSDateFormatter.new;
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
    return [formatter dateFromString:theDate];
}

@end
```

you can even customize it further by using a static `date` variable and then modify it in the test

```
-(void) test_something_out {
 theDate = @"2017-12-28 13:00:10+0000";
 //Test any function that uses nsdate.date
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to test methods that use Date() (or CLLocationManager, ReachabilityManager, or anything else static), is to set up an environment for your entire app which can be mocked in tests.

To do this, create an Environment class like so:

```
struct Environment {

    var date: () -> Date = Date.init
}

var Env = Environment()
```

Throughout the rest of your app, access the current date via `Env.date()` instead of calling `Date()`.

In your tests, create a mock environment like this:

```
extension Environment {

    static let mock = Environment(
        date: {
            return Date(year: 2019, month: 11, day: 12, hour: 2, minute: 45, second: 0, millisecond: 0, timeZone: TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "CST"))
        }
    )
}
```

And in the setup for your tests, replace the app environment with the mock env like this:

```
override func setUp() {

    super.setUp()

    Env = .mock
}
```

I'd recommend putting that in a base class that all your test classes will inherit from so every test will use the mock environment.

Now when you run your app you will see the current date, but in tests the date will always come back as Nov. 12, 2019 02:45, so you can verify whatever you want from that known date.

For a working example of this setup, I've created a little demo project [here](https://github.com/BevTheDev/Paradigms). Environment.swift, MockEnvironment.swift, DateExamplesViewController.swift, and DateTests.swift are the relevant files.

Comment: Just saying: I _expect_ that two calls to Date() on iOS or MacOS one second apart usually return dates one second apart (although that's not guaranteed). Your code will always return the same date. Lots of code would break in that situation.

Comment: @gnasher729 If you run that code in a playground, you'll see that Env.date() returns a different date on each call. When you replace Env with .mock, Env.date() will return the same date on each call, which is the expected behavior. If your test needs unique dates, then you wouldn't want to use the mock environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `Date.now()` like this, it will be very easy and clean to implement

```
extension Date {
    static var now: (()->Date) = {
        return Date()
    }
}

print(Date.now())
Date.now = { Date().addingTimeInterval(43534543) }
print(Date.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple workaround can be to use following approach:

1. Create a mock class that derives from the class under test.
2. Add a method like "getDate()->NSDate", in the class under test, that
       returns "NSDate()"- or whatever value is expected.
3. Override the
       getDate() in the mockClass. You can also create a variable in mock
       class, that is returned from getDate(). With this, you will be able
       to supply whatever date you want to from the test.
4. Lastly, instead of creating instance of class that you wish to test,
   create the
       instance of mock class in your test.

Comment: That is a really bad solution, I should have not to change my class like that in order to test it.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz he's not saying to change your class- he's saying to create a mock class under test.  Mocking is the only way to effectively test sometimes.

Comment: Mocks are meant to replace dependencies, not to replace the class you want to test. This way you're not testing your class, you're testing the mock.

Comment: For dates, you really want a mocking class. For example, to make sure that your code works correctly on Dec 31st and Jan 1st (lots of bugs happen around that time).

Answer (score 0):

NSDate.date (Objective C), Date() (Swift), Date.now() in other languages, are all problematic to mock, because they are *supposed* to give different results on different calls.

So if I add an object to a database with the current date, and check that when I read it from the database it has the current date, that's not going to work. Not because there's anything wrong with the database, or with the Date.now() function, but with the way you use it.

Mocking Date.now() to always return the same date to make your test work is fundamentally flawed, because the mocked Date.now() doesn't work the way it is supposed to work! Two calls in a row are supposed to return different dates, not the same one!

The correct way: Create a date object D, any way you like. Add an object with the date D, write it to the database, read it from the database, check that the date of the object is D. Then check what the database documentation says about precision: If it stores the date as seconds, and you store a date with milliseconds, then either you change the definition of the object ("This object rounds all dates to whole seconds"), or you accept that writing + reading returns an object with a slightly different date, and change the unit test accordingly.

So what you do is document what behaviour you expect, make the unit test test the expected behaviour, and on failure you decide if the unit test was wrong, or your code was wrong, or the expected behaviour should have been different. (Unit tests can have bugs as well, and specs for expected behaviour can have bugs).